# Adding a Map into list. The map is created when looping a list

Tags: java

I have `getSemiFileInfos()` in a list and I wanted to use stream and then loop each of element inside. Each element can still use `getItem()` or `getItem2()`. I will first create a map for `item` and `item2` in `itemMap`, then I will store each loop of `getSemiFileInfos()` as a map into `items` list.

What I want is to have it in a single line. I am wondering whether is still possible.

```
private List<Map<String, String>> items;

items = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

Map<String, String> itemMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
file.getFileInfo().getSemiFileInfos().stream().forEach(m-> 
    itemMap.put("item", m.getItem()); 
    itemMap.put("item2", m.getItem2().split(":",1))
);
items.add(mrphMap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map each element of your `Stream` into a `Map` with `map()` and then collect into a `List`:

```
List<Map<String, String>> items =
    file.getFileInfo()
        .getSemiFileInfos()
        .stream() 
        .map(m-> {
            Map<String, String> itemMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            itemMap.put("item", m.getItem()); 
            itemMap.put("item2", m.getItem2().split(":",1)); // this doesn't produce a String
                                                             // value so perhaps you are
                                                             // missing some additional logic
                                                             // that would  extract one 
                                                             // String from the String[]
            return itemMap;
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```